# GUNICORN ERROR: Application object must be callable

Tags: python, github, render, gunicorn, dashboard

everyone! Still relatively new to coding in Python and working with GitHub and Render, so please let me know if I need to include more information here.

I recently completed creating a dashboard through Python (utilizing Plotly for visualizations) to better analyze baseball data that I collected over the summer. My code, which contains a primary "app.py" file and five page files (under a folder labeled "pages"), runs perfectly on VS Code. I've uploaded all of these pages, the app.py file, and associated csv files onto the same spot on GitHub.

However, every time I try uploading this GitHub repository onto Render, I get the following error: gunicorn.errors.AppImportError: Application object must be callable.

This is an example of what my app.py file looks like. This is what I've tried uploading:

```
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

pages_folder = os.path.join(current_dir, 'pages')

data_file1 = os.path.join(pages_folder, 'first.csv')
data_file2 = os.path.join(pages_folder, 'second.csv')
data_file3 = os.path.join(pages_folder, 'third.csv')
data_file4 = os.path.join(pages_folder, 'fourth.csv')

one = pd.read_csv(data_file1)
two = pd.read_csv(data_file2)
three = pd.read_csv(data_file3)
four = pd.read_csv(data_file4)

app = Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.JOURNAL],use_pages=True)
server = app.server
app.title = 'Baseball Dashboard'

app.layout = dbc.Container(
# everything in this code included for app design
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```